# How to delete libraries in ModelSim/QuestaSim?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I’ve done many projects on this software and I want to delete a big ammount of libraries that are useless and now are giving me errors to simulate my new projects I think the best option is to delete old files(libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- delete the matching directories on disk and edit the `modelsim.ini` file(s) by hand, or
- use `vdel.exe`.

**Usage of `vdel`:**

```
PS> .\vdel.exe -h
Usage: vdel -help
       vdel [-lib <path>] [-modelsimini <ini_filepath>] [-verbose] { -all | <primary> [<secondary>] | -allsystemc |  [-dpiobj [<platform>|<compiler>| <platform_compiler> |all] ]  [-obj [<platform>|<compiler>|<platform_compiler>|all] ]}
```

Comment: Is there any way that you can delete them by hand, I mean, you go to an especific folder and then you delete the useless files, anyway I will try yours

Comment: That's item one in my answer.